# speed up re.match() on a list of string?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose `s` is a long list of strings. I'd like to extract the indexes of the elements in the list that matches the regex. But when the list is very long, the runtime can be slow. Is there a way to speed up the search?

```
regex = re.compile('^x.*$')
result = [i for i,v in enumerate(s) if regex.match(v)]
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected output as well

Comment: Why don't you iterate on the list, and check if each element begins with an "s"?

Comment: Is that the actual regex you're using? You do not need a regex here (and even with a regex, building `.*$` into the search does a bunch of unnecessary work).

Answer (score 0):

If all what you want to do is check if the string begins with an "x", you can use `startswith`:

```
result = [i for i, v in enumerate(s) if v.startswith("x")]
```

---

```
$ python -m timeit -n 1000 -s 'import re; regex = re.compile("^x.*$");' '[i for i,v in enumerate(["xax", "y", "xaff"]) if regex.match(v)]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.62 usec per loop
$ python -m  timeit -n 1000 '[i for i, v in enumerate(["xax", "y", "xaff"]) if v.startswith("x")]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.17 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the list into chunks and use python multiprocessing or multithreading. Find the index of matches for each chunk, and add the index of the beginning of each chunk to your matches so that the final indexes match the overall index in the list.